# R: Packaging a function with trace

Tags: r, r-package

We have some internal R packages with a very large number of functions. As part of an effort to eliminate unused code I looked into `covr` and `codetools::checkUsage` and both are insufficient - so we opted to hook all functions with `trace` that would record activity somewhere. Toy example with no technical details:

```r
> f <- function() { print("Doing very very important work")  }
> trace(f, tracer=substitute(print("recording call")))
[1] "f"
> f()
Tracing f() on entry 
[1] "recording call"
[1] "Doing very very important work"
```

The tracer operation does not significantly delay the work, but the tracing all package functions (~35K) takes ~3 minutes - and I'm looking for ways to shorten it.

Is there some way to package the functions *with the trace*, so it won't have to be added in a separate post-load stage? Is there another direction I didn't think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `trace()` calls into the source for your package.  Just make sure the `trace()` call happens after the function definition, either by putting it later in the same source file, or by putting it in a separate file that collates after all your function definitions.

For example, if your package has a file `R/fun.R` containing this source,

```r
fun <- function(x) {
   print('this is fun!')
}
```

then simply add another line to `R/fun.R` so it looks like this instead:

```r
fun <- function(x) {
   print('this is fun!')
}

trace(fun, tracer=substitute(print("recording call")))
```

This works because of the way R installs and traces things:

- trace modifies functions to insert the tracing.
- installing executes all of the source files in the R directory, and saves the results.

So putting a trace call in your source will modify the function before it is saved, and it will stay modified for any user of that package.

Comment: You mean like inside the package's `.onLoad`? How would that save the long tracing time?

Comment: No, I added an example to show what I meant.

Comment: This will probably increase the install time for your package, but that only happens once.  Each run after installing will already have the traces installed.

Comment: This seems identical to what I'm doing today outside the package. Once per session too. Why would doing this inside the package save anything?

Comment: Do you only use your package once, and then reinstall it?  In that case, it won't save anything.  If you use it more than once, you'll save time.

Comment: By the way, if you have 35K functions, I would assume they are machine generated, not individually written.  Then it would probably make more sense to change the generation code to insert something to record each call instead of using `trace()` at all.

Comment: The functions are mostly hand coded. Not sure what you mean by 'used once' - it is loaded (via `library`) once per R session. It makes no difference if the `trace` is executed as part of the loading or after it - I wish the loaded package would have included the trace, but maybe that's not possible.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but you are wrong about when `trace()` is executed.  It is executed just once during the package install, and not when you load the package.  The loaded package includes the modified functions.

Comment: I'd guess that you put your `trace()` calls inside `.onLoad()`, as you suggested at the beginning.  That's the wrong way to do it.  Follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much!  Currently I'm extracting the list of functions to trace via something like `ls(env="package:myPkg", all.names=TRUE)`, but I'll devise a different way and try it during package evaluation. Accepting this answer for now.

Comment: A simple call to `ls(all.names = TRUE)` will find all the functions that have been defined up to that point.  Putting it in `zzz.R` should mean that you capture all the functions in the package.